# Android add/replace Items within RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I know there are lots of threads already on this topic, but none of the given solutions worked for me so far. I'm trying to add or update an item of a `RecyclerView`. Here's my code so far:

**MainActivity**

```
private MyListItemAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

// called on activity create
private void init() {
    // initialize activity, load items, etc ...
    mAdapter = new MyListItemAdapter(this, items);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

// called when I want to replace an item
private void updateItem(final Item newItem, final int pos) {
    mAdapter.replaceItem(newItem, pos);
}
```

**MyListItemAdapter**

```
public class MyListItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListItemAdapter.MyListItemViewHolder> {

    private List<Item> mItems;

    public void replaceItem(final Item newItem, final int pos) {
        mItems.remove(position);
        mItems.add(position, newItem);

        notifyItemChanged(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }    
}
```

I tried to make this changes from the `MainActivity` aswell, but in every case I tried my list doesn't get updated. The only way it worked was when I reset the adapter to the recyclerView:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

which obviously is a bad idea. (aside from the bad side effects wouldn't even work when I'm using lazy loading on my lists).

So my question is, how can I make `notifyDataSetChanged()` work properly?

**edit**

I found a solution for replacing items. After `mAdapter.replaceItem(newItem, pos);` I had to call `recyclerView.removeViewAt(position);`

This works for replacing an item, but doesn't solve my problem when I want to add items (e.g. lazy loading) to my list

**edit2**

I found a working solution for adding items

Adapter:

```
public void addItem(final Item newItem) {
    mItems.add(newItem);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Activity:

```
private void addItem(final Item newItem) {
    mAdapter.addItem(newItem);
    recyclerView.removeViewAt(0); // without this line nothing happens
}
```

For some reason this works (also: it doesn't remove the view at position 0), but I'm sure this isn't the correct way to add items to a recyclerView

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
private ArrayList<Item> mItems;

public void replaceItem(final Item newItem, final int position) {
    mItems.set(position, newItem);
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

`ArrayList.set()` is the way to go to replace items.

For adding items, just append them to `mItems` and then go `notifyDatasetChanged()`. Another way to go is to use `notifyItemRangeInserted()`. Depending on where/how are you adding new items and how many of them, it might be worth it.

Comment: set works, but only in cooperation with `recyclerView.removeViewAt(position);` which is fine for replacing items, but doesn't help me for adding new items -> `mItems.add(item)` + `notifyDatasetChanged()` / `notifyItemRangeInserted(mItems.size() -1, 1) ` does nothing

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 mItems.set(position, newItem);
```

instead of

```
 mItems.add(position, newItem);
```

because `.set` method will replace your data to particular position.